# Python super().__init__() doesn't call multiple inherited classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In my example i have two classes `FirstClass` `SecondClass`

```
class FirstClass():
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("First class instance creation")
        pass
    
class SecondClass():
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Second class instance creation")
        pass
```

After inherting them in `SampleClass` like this

```
class SampleClass(FirstClass, SecondClass):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        super(SecondClass, self).__init__()
```

but its not calling the `SecondClass`,

```
FirstClass.__init__(self=self)
SecondClass.__init__(self=self)
```

but this method works,

MY QUESTIONS IS:
Why its working like this ?, How super() function will work in multiple inheritances?

I'm trying to trigger both inherited classes using super() method

This is what I'm getting while using super() method

```
First class instance creation
```

but it is not working as i expected,

this is what i expecting

```
First class instance creation
Second class instance creation
```

Second class instance creation